# Shiny Issue - Tracking User Settings in Multiuser Environment

Tags: r, user-interface, shiny

I asked this question on the Shiny user group, but haven't been able to get a response, so I'm posting it here as well.

I have an app that needs to track a user's preference, with the possibility that several users may be using the app simultaneously.  For simplicity, let's say I have a list to contain a user's settings stored within the shiny server function. It's a long list (1000 elements) that contains attributes based on the user's interaction with the app. The user can in effect change any index of this list to one of hundreds of possible settings. My initial solution was something like this:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
 settings <<- rep("A",1000)

 observe({
      input$changeSettingsButton
      settings[input$changeIndex] <<- input$newSetting
 })
}
```

Which works great unless you have multiple people using the app at the same time, because the <<- creates a global, shared variable across sessions. Is there a good way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `reactiveValues` to store persistent user info. Something like

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  myReactives <- reactiveValues(settings = rep("A",1000))

  observe({
    input$changeSettingsButton
    isolate(myReactives$settings[input$changeIndex] <- input$newSetting)
  })
}
```

may work for you.

Comment: How is a reactiveValues persistent? A browser refresh will reset it to its initial value right? Unless you need the reactive benefits of a reactive object `settings <- rep("A",1000)` would do the same thing wouldn't it?

Comment: @Vincent `settings <<-  rep("A",1000)` would be applied across all sessions. `reactiveValues` allows the variable to persist across that particular users session.

Comment: I understand that `<<-`  would be applied across all sessions. However, I didn't suggest  `<<-` but only `<-`. For the OP's question, reactiveValues will be no more persistent than a normal variable defined as `settings <- rep("A",1000)` in shinyServer. Both would be reset to their original value by a browser refresh. My comment is about the word 'persistent' and how it differs (or rather doesn't) for reactiveValues vs regular variables and lists defined in shinyServer using `<-`.